# C# Created Barcodes Scanning Different Values Than Those Encoded

Tags: c#, barcode

I am working on a C# program that creates and displays UPCA barcodes (using the NuGet package BarCodeLib). These barcodes seem to work perfectly, until you scan them at least. When they are scanned, I've seen the scanned number be up to 3 more or less than the encoded value. Sometimes they're 2 off, sometimes 1 off, and rarely they actually match. Could this be an image size issue? Could a barcode being disproportionately tall or wide cause this issue?

```
public string barcodePath
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    string dir = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BarcodeDirectory"];
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
                    BarcodeLib.Barcode b = new BarcodeLib.Barcode();
                    string oid = recipientId.ToString();
                    char[] array = oid.ToCharArray();
                    int end = 12 - oid.Length;
                    for (int i = 0; i < end; i++)
                    {
                        oid = "0" + oid;
                    }

                    Image img = b.Encode(BarcodeLib.TYPE.UPCA, oid, Color.Black, Color.White, 290, 201); //290, 120
                    string imgPath = dir + @"\" + recipientId + ".jpg";
                    img.Save(imgPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    return "file:///" + imgPath;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return "";
                }
            }
```

These two barcodes were created sequentially within a loop.

48989 - Scans fine
[image: 48989]

48990 - Scans to 48996
[image]

Comment: Without seeing any code, it'll be a wild guess, but this sort of thing easily happens when you let some codes inappropriately get treated as e.g. floating point numbers at some point during your processing.

Comment: There are no floating point numbers - and I have verified 100% that the proper number is being sent into the library. I can provide any code desired, but I don't know what would help for that reason. -- I have been googling for a while with no help, I would appreciate some constructive feedback before this thread is closed (which it seems to be on the way to doing..)

Comment: Because without code, this isn't even a programming question. The questions you've asked are just about barcode dimensions affecting readability. We don't even know if you're printing these things out on something like paper or you're trying to scan them from the screen.

Comment: There's some code. Will it help answer the question? I don't see how it would, but have at it. And by the way if there was a barcodeOverflow website, I would definitely be asking over there.

Comment: How so? Like I mentioned in the question, i was wondering if proportions might cause the bad scan. I changed the dimensions, tested again, and got the same results. That's why I asked this question...

Comment: Some example input values & the incorrect output values may be useful as well as your code

Comment: `Could this be an image size issue?` Unlikely as the barcodes are supposed to have lines to indicate the start and finish as well as a checksum in order to make it very very difficult to get a false reading.

Comment: Thank you for actually addressing my question. I'm wondering if this library can be trusted, although it has 20K+ downloads. I'm going to revert to an older version of the library and see it that fixes anything.

Comment: I think what may be happening is you are zero-padding to 12 digits & the library is taking the first (or last) 11 digits & auto-generating the final checksum digit. Try zero padding to 11 digits & then scanning.

Comment: If your barcode package allows you to print the barcode number at the bottom of the barcode, it would tell you if the barcode being printed is exactly what you asked for. (In could be that 48990 is an invalid barcode number and the software is correcting the last digit as a checksum).

Comment: And that's why you post the code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the library is doing is correcting the final digit of your 12 digit, zero padded number.

See this comment from http://codeproject.com/Articles/20823/Barcode-Image-Generation-Library *"◦The UPC-A check digit is now calculated every time whether 11 or 12 digits are passed in. If 12 is passed in and it has got an incorrect check digit, then it is replaced with the correct check digit. This prevents an unscannable barcode from being generated."*

The correct check digit for "00000004898" is 9. For "00000004899" it is 6.

You could just zero-pad your number to 11 digits & allow the library to add the correct checksum value - or do it yourself - see : http://www.makebarcode.com/specs/upc_a.html